# Add external data to Orika MappingContext while mapping

Tags: java, orika

I want to add some external properties (something not in the object I'm mapping) to the MappingContext.

Here what I want to accomplish:

```
    MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
    mapperFactory.classMap(ObjA.class, ObjB.class).customize(new CustomMapper<ObjA, ObjB>() {
        @Override
        public void mapAtoB(ObjA objA, ObjB objB, MappingContext context) {
            objB.setName((String) context.getProperty("name"));
        }
    }).byDefault().register();
    MapperFacade mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();

    ObjA objA = new ObjA();
    ObjB objB = new ObjB();

    MappingContext context = new MappingContext(); //PROBLEME IS HERE: MappingContext is a abstract class
    context.setProperty("name", "Some information not in objA nor in objB");
    mapper.map(objA, objB, context);
```

How can I do that? Can I dynamically add data to the context? Or is it an other way to pass additional data to mapper?

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you just posted? Looks like the right way to go.

Comment: @AdamMichalik MappingContext is abstract and cannot be instantiated. I didn't find a way to extract the actual mapper context nor to build a new one with a MappingContextFactory

Comment: [`MappingContext.Factory.getContext()`](http://javadox.com/ma.glasnost.orika/orika-core/1.4.0/ma/glasnost/orika/MappingContext.Factory.html#getContext())? Seems you should call `release()` once you're done with the context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is simple:

```
MappingContext context = new MappingContext.Factory().getContext();
context.setProperty("name", "value");
mapper.map(objA, objB, context);
```